# Why is the output of this code 10, 0, 0 using a C++ GCCv7.1.1 compiler?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
# define swap(a,b) temp=a; a=b; b=temp;

using namespace std;
int main( )
{
    int i, j, temp;
    i=5;
    j=10;
    temp=0;
    if( i > j)
       swap( i, j );
    cout << i <<" ";
    cout <<j << " "<< temp;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try using `g++ -E` and see what the code looks like. Conclusion: don't use macros.

Comment: You are missing a pair of braces around your macro call: `{ swap( i, j ); }`. Do yourself a favor and don't use macros. Prefer a inline function instead.

Comment: There already exists a swap function in the C++ standard library. Why do you mess around with macros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that macros do direct modification of source code.

```
if( i > j)
   swap( i, j );
cout << i <<" ";
```

therefore becomes

```
if (i > j)
    temp = i;
i = j;
j = temp;
cout << i <<" ";
```

where I've used indenting to emphasise that the statements `i = j;` and `j = temp;` are executed, whether `i > j` or not.   This will happen with any C++ (and C) compiler (or preprocessor) - it is not specific to gcc.

If you MUST use macros, you need to make the macro work correctly in such use cases.  For example;

```
#define swap(a,b) do {temp=a; a=b; b=temp;} while (0)
```

ensures that all three assignments happen together, even in cases like

```
if (i > j) swap(i, j);
```

Practically, macros are actively discouraged in C++ because there are better alternatives, such as using the standard library

```
if (i > j) std::swap(i, j);
```

where `std::swap()` is available in standard header `<algorithm>` (before C++11) or `<utility>` (C++11 and later).

If you really insist on writing your own code rather than using the standard library, write a function for the purpose, not a macro.   Depending on needs, the function can be written as an `inline` function or templated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that when you compile your code the macro is replaced by it's definition. So your code becones:

```
if(i > j) temp=i; i=j; j=temp;
```

Since you do not have {} around the swap call only the first part of the swap (namely `temp=i`) is part of the if. The next two commands are executed every time. The correct way would be:

```
if(i > j) { swap(i, j); }
```